# Error returned from Mono not being caught in onErrorResume

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flux

I'm using **RxJava 2** for reactive programming through micronaut framework. I'm trying to understand an issue with the following code:

```
fun getItemDetails(
    itemRequest: RequestTo
): Mono<List<ResponseTo>> {
    return itemRequest.itemIdList.toFlux()
        .flatMap { findItemStatus(it) }
        .flatMap { response ->
            Mono.justOrEmpty(ResponseTo(response))
                .onErrorResume {
                    logger.error("Error occurred while mapping entity to response: $response", it)
                    Mono.empty()
                }
        }
        .collectList()
}
```

RequestTo: consists of a list of String.
The idea is to iterate over this list, get the details for each item from the DB(processed through  `findItemStatus()` function call which returns the DB Entity) and Map it to a response object.

I wanted to work such that, if any entity returned by the `findItemStatus() flatMap` operation causes an exception while mapping it to the `ResponseTo`, I want that item to be skipped in the final list but continue processing the remaining items in the flux. I don't want to keep the `onErrorResume` block outside the second flatMap cause that would close the stream if any intermediate entity in the flux causes an Error while mapping and the remaining items in the flux won't be mapped.

I'm not sure what the issue is with my code but when there is an exception thrown in `Mono.justOrEmpty(ResponseTo(response))`, it is not being caught in onErrorResume.

I'm putting the test case here:

```
def "test getItemDetails() when there is an error mapping DB response to Response TO for any item"() {

        def itemEntity1 = new DiscontinuedItemsEntity("52782904", null, null, UUID.randomUUID())
        def itemEntity2 = new DiscontinuedItemsEntity("52778904", null, null, UUID.randomUUID())
        def requestBody = new DiscontinuedItemsTcinRequest(["52782904", "52782904"])

        when:
        def response = itemsStatusService.getItemDetails(requestBody).block()
        def responseList = response.itemsList

        then:
        1 * discontinuedItemsRepository.findDiscontinuedItems(*_) >> Mono.just(itemEntity1)
        1 * discontinuedItemsRepository.findDiscontinuedItems(*_) >> Mono.just(itemEntity2)

        responseList.size() == 1
        responseList.get(0).itemId == itemEntity1.itemId
    }
```

I need this test case to pass but instead an exception is thrown and not handled since it's not being caught in onErrorResume